# File Uploader element in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I am new to angular js and am trying to create a simple file uploading element. Following is my angular js code

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm" id="fileUploader">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                Browse<input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="csvFile" name="file" accept=".csv"></input>
            </span>
        </span>         
        <input type="text" id="fileInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose file" readonly></input>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Ok</button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

When I click on browse button and choose a file, I want the file name to appear on the `fileInput` element. Can anyone help me on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `'fileinput'` input try setting `value={{csvFile.name}}`. This should work if you have everything dependency injected correctly & all that.